# Get resource consumption details and costing of Azure VM using REST

Tags: rest, azure

I am in need to get current resource consumption details of specific VM and the costing of that VM according to consumption using REST api.

[Want Azure API to which I can pass the VM name/id and result would be Usage details and cost. They do have usage and Rate card API End Points but again it needs taking one Val from Usage and one relative from Rate multiplying it to get total]

Comment: Please tell us what you have tried so far (show us the code) and what are the issues you're running into.

Comment: I am not able to find the Azure API to which I can pass the VM name/id and result would be Usage details and costing. They do have usage API, Rate card API but again not able to parse there response.

Answer (score 2):

Is that what you are looking for?

> The Azure billing API allows to get data of your usage and the money
>   that you have to pay for your resources.
>
> https://codehollow.com/2017/02/using-the-azure-billing-api-to-calculate-the-costs/

Azure Billing REST API Reference:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/mt218998.aspx

Comment: Partially not. In first reference link, they are using some **AzureBillingApi** .Net library. I can not use it coz I use Python.And I already have gone through the second msdn link, in which they are giving Rate Card and Usage details. I can take the usage value and rate from Rate card, then Total cost=rate*usage. I dont want this, I want Azure API to which I can pass the VM name/id and result would be Usage details and costing. thanx for help :)

Comment: What about this one https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/mt219001.aspx ? You can get all of the consumption details, except the cost, but you can calculate it yourself. I don't think that there is another option.

Comment: Can u please elaborate your sentence **" cost, but you can calculate it yourself."** How?

Comment: The way that you said you don't want to ( Rate card -> MeterRates, Quantity..). What is the problem with that solution?

Comment: Okay, It seems I need to go with custom logic which I knew already. They don't have any endpoint which will help directly satisfy requirements. BTW thanx for the help. :)